# Comparing models

Tags: modeling, chi-squared-test, references, goodness-of-fit

Suppose that I have two models, A and B (A nested in B), which are tailored to explain data from a single participant in an experiment. Example: I am modeling response times in a single participant. However, I have 20 participants.

I can fit A and B using MLE to each participant independently, and then obtain likelihood ratios for each participant and test the significance with a chi-square test. But how can I make inferences over the population?

I read in one (rather obscure and not totally trusted) source that I can simply sum the $\chi^2$ values for each participant. The resulting value will be $\chi^2$ with df=20 in this case.

1. Is this a valid procedure?
2. Can you recommend any sources that go into detail about this sort of method of aggregating model fits?

Bonus: What if my models aren't nested, but all of the above is still true?

Comment: "*how can I make inferences over the population?*" - if I follow what you're saying, it sounds like you want mixed effects models, where participant has a random effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Glen_b that you seem to be looking for mixed models. You can use a variant of Akaike's Information Criterion for model selection here. Bonus: AIC works for non-nested models. [Here is a reference](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/92/2/351).

Comment: I see, so I should assume individual-level parameters are drawn from overarching distributions; the fitting step is now to estimate the parameters of those distributions. Then I'd compare based on AIC...